# XSLT order variables according to their sequence in a reference file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have list of links that need to be ordered according to their order of appearance in a sitemap xml file.

So far I've managed to group the links by their parent module number, but each group's links are organized alphabetically. I need the links in each list, and each sublist, to fall in the order they fall in the sitemap xml file.

I'm using XSLT 3.

### XML needing to be ordered

```
    <article>
       <ul>
           <li data-mod="module4">
              <a href="../module4/irregular-headers.html">Irregular headers</a>
           </li>
           <li data-mod="module4">
              <a href="../module4/multi-level-headers.html">Multi-level headers</a>
           </li>
           <li data-mod="module3">
              <a href="../module3/navigation.html">Navigation</a>
              <ul>
                  <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#focus">Focus and focus order</a>
                  </li>
                  <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#blocks-navigation">Blocks of navigation</a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- <li>[etc.]</li> -->
              </ul>
           </li>
           <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/tables-concepts.html">Tables concepts</a>
           </li>
           <li data-mod="module4">
              <a href="../module4/two-headers.html">Two headers</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </article>
```

### XML sitemap with correct sequence

```
    <section data-mod="module3">
       <h2 class="wb-inv">Module 3 - Links and navigation</h2>
       <details id="toggle3">
          <summary>Module 3 - Links and navigation</summary>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <a href="../module3/links.html">Links</a>
                <ul>
                   <li>
                      <a href="../module3/links.html#link-purpose">Link purpose</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                      <a href="../module3/links.html#link-activation">Link activation</a>
                   </li>
                   <!-- <li>[etc.]</li> -->
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li>
                <a href="../module3/navigation.html#link-purpose">Navigation</a>
                <ul>
                   <li>
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#blocks-navigation">Blocks of navigation</a>
                   </li>
                  <li>
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#focus">Focus and focus order</a>
                  </li>
                   <!-- <li>[etc.]</li> -->
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </details>
    </section>
    <section data-mod="module4">
       <h2 class="wb-inv">Module 4 - Tables</h2>
       <details>
           <summary class="bg-info">Module 4 – Tables</summary>
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="../module4/tables-concepts.html">Tables concepts</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="../module4/one-header.html">One header</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="../module4/two-headers.html">Two header</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="../module4/irregular-headers.html">Irregular headers</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="../module4/multi-level-headers.html">Multi-level headers</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </details>
    </section>
```

### XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match="ul[parent::article]">
       <ul>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-by="@data-mod">
             <xsl:sort select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/>
             <xsl:variable name="mod" as="xs:string" select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/>

             <li><xsl:value-of select="$sitemap//section[./@data-mod=$mod]/h2/text()"/></li>
             <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="fn:current-group()">
                   <!-- don't know who to order by appearance in the sitemap.xml -->
                   <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
             </ul>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </ul>           
    </xsl:template>
```

### XML output

```
    <article>
       <ul>
          <li>Module 3 - Links and navigation</li>
          <ul>
             <li data-mod="module3">
                <a href="../module3/navigation.html#link-purpose">Navigation</a>
                <ul>
                  <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#focus">Focus and focus order</a>
                  </li>
                   <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#blocks-navigation">Blocks of navigation</a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
          <li>Module 4 - Tables</li>
          <ul>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/irregular-headers.html">Irregular headers</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/multi-level-headers.html">Multi-level headers</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/tables-concepts.html">Tables concepts</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/two-headers.html">Two headers</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </ul>
    </article>
```

### Desired output

```
    <article>
       <ul>
          <li>Module 3 - Links and navigation</li>
          <ul>
             <!-- these are now in the correct order -->
             <li data-mod="module3">
                <a href="../module3/navigation.html#link-purpose">Navigation</a>
                <ul>
                   <!-- these are now in the correct order -->
                   <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#blocks-navigation">Blocks of navigation</a>
                   </li>
                  <li data-mod="module3">
                      <a href="../module3/navigation.html#focus">Focus and focus order</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
          <li>Module 4 - Tables</li>
          <ul>
             <!-- these are now in the correct order -->
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/tables-concepts.html">Tables concepts</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/two-headers.html">Two headers</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/irregular-headers.html">Irregular headers</a>
             </li>
             <li data-mod="module4">
                <a href="../module4/multi-level-headers.html">Multi-level headers</a>
             </li>
          </ul>
       </ul>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `<xsl:key name="section-by-module" match="section" use="@data-mod"/>` to reference the section elements in the sitemap file, then use e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="hrefs" select="key('section-by-module', current-grouping-key(), $sitemap)//li/a/@href/string()"/>
```

and then use e.g.

```
<xsl:sequence select="sort(current-group(), (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) }"/>
```

That might suffice for the module4 where your group seems to have all `li` elements as siblings in the input XML. For the module3 group it rather seems that you need to process the grouped elements with a mode/templates that recursively group child/descendants `li` elements e.g.

```
<xsl:mode name="sort-lis" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis">
  <xsl:with-param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes" select="$hrefs"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and then e.g.

```
<xsl:template mode="sort-lis" match="ul">
  <xsl:param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(li, (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis"/> 
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To show it all in context, the `xsl:key` declaration and the `xsl:mode` declaration, like the `xsl:template`, are used as top-level elements/direct children of the `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform`) root element of your XSLT code, the variable and the apply-templates needs to be used in your template instead of the `for-each` you had:

```
<xsl:key name="section-by-module" match="section" use="@data-mod"/>

<xsl:mode name="sort-lis" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template mode="sort-lis" match="ul">
   <xsl:param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes"/>
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(li, (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis"/> 
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[parent::article]">
       <ul>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="li" group-by="@data-mod">
             <xsl:sort select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/>
             <xsl:variable name="mod" as="xs:string" select="fn:current-grouping-key()"/>

             <li><xsl:value-of select="$sitemap//section[./@data-mod=$mod]/h2/text()"/></li>
             <ul>
               <xsl:variable name="hrefs" select="key('section-by-module', current-grouping-key(), $sitemap)//li/a/@href/string()"/>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis">
                 <xsl:with-param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes" select="$hrefs"/>
               </xsl:apply-templates>                
             </ul>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </ul>           
</xsl:template>
```

If using the higher-order sort function doesn't work as it should with your rather old release of Altova you could of course test whether a classic `xsl:sort` works at least by replacing

```
           <xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis">
             <xsl:with-param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes" select="$hrefs"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
```

with

```
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="sort-lis">
             <xsl:sort select="index-of($hrefs, a/@href)"/>
             <xsl:with-param name="hrefs" tunnel="yes" select="$hrefs"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
```

(And then probably you have to do the same for the other use of `sort` e.g. to replace

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(li, (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href) })" mode="sort-lis"/>
```

with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="sort-lis">
  <xsl:sort select="index-of($hrefs, a/@href)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Martin. Can I bother you to combine the various parts into a single script? I'm not sure where to position your code. There's a bunch of stuff in here I've never tried, like current-grouping-key() in a key variable, function(), index-of, xs:mode and on-no-match="shallow-copy". I need to study!

Comment: @JeffOrchard, see whether the edit helps.

Comment: Thanks, the context is terrific help. But I'm afraid I'm getting this error on the xsl:apply-templates/@select:  Unexpected argument type: 'function(item()*) as xs:integer*

this one: 
<xsl:apply-templates select="sort(current-group(), (), function($li) ...

Comment: Which XSLT processor gives that error? Does using `sort(li, (), function($li) { index-of($hrefs, $li/a/@href)[1] })` instead avoid the error?

Comment: I use Altova XMLSpy 2017 sp2. Unfortunately, that variant throws the same error.

Comment: I think the code runs fine with current versions of Saxon Java and JS. I don't remember which release of Altova was the first to implement XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1, perhaps ask their support whether that rather old release should be up to the task of XSLT 3.0 with XPath 3.1.

Comment: I tried the code now with Altova XMLSpy 2018 rel. 2 sp1 and it works fine

Comment: I tested on a trial version of XMLSpy 2022 and it works like a charm. Thanks so much! Time to update ...

Comment: Tested the classic sort and it works as well.